# AngularJs - not able to get data from external file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, angular-ui-bootstrap

Unable to get data from PHP file as well as JSON file

timesheet.php

```
require 'dbconnect.php';

$array_data = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM timesheet";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($array_data);
$result_data = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

if( !empty($result_data) ) {    

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $json = json_encode($result_data);
    // echo $json;
    echo preg_replace("/null/", '""', $json); // replace null to ""

}
```

timesheet.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "20th August 2016",
        "day": "Sat",
        "in1": "10:30",
        "out1": "02:30",
        "in2": "04:00",
        "out2": "08:00",
        "in3": "",
        "out3": "",
        "total_hours": "8:00",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {   
        "id": 2,
        "date": "20th August 2016",
        "day": "Sat",
        "in1": "10:30",
        "out1": "02:30",
        "in2": "04:00",
        "out2": "08:00",
        "in3": "",
        "out3": "",
        "total_hours": "8:00",
        "status": "1"
    }
    ...
]
```

controller.js

```
.controller('tableCtrl', function($filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {

        var data = tableService.data
    //Editable
        this.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
        }, {
            total:data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    })
```

script.js

```
.service('tableService', ['$http', function($http){

        this.data = $http.get("data/timesheet.php")
        //this.data = $http.get("data/timesheet.json")

    }])
```

html

```
<table ng-table="tctrl.tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
       <tr ng-repeat="w in $data"  ng-class="{ 'active': w.$edit }">
          <td data-title="'ID'">
             <span ng-if="!w.$edit">{{ w.id }}</span>
             <div ng-if="w.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="w.id" /></div>
          </td>
          ...
       </tr>                        
   </table>
```

When I put json data in service.js like this.data = [{..}] it's working but now I need to get data from exterrnal file which can be either JSON file or a PHP file but it's not working as I am getting empty table. Can anyone please help me? I am very new to AngularJs

Comment: I think you are trying to access a files that not exist yet. So you should use promise or callback for that php file, because the data is ready only after php is done processing. It works with JSON cause the data is there static,ready anytime, but php needs to compute the data from db and create a json response( same as json content), but it takes time.

Comment: Http request in not going to return instantly. It is an async call and has to be handled differently then what you are doing. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: @DincaAdrian It is not working with timesheet.json also. Its working only when I write json data directly in service.js. Please can you provide some example code that how can I use promise or callback here?

Comment: @VladimirM Okay! but can you please tell me that how can I handle it? I am totally blank about it.

Comment: @User7 Have you followed the link I've attached tot he comment? There is an example of angular get request. It returns a promise. You really have to read a documentation about these, if you plan to use angular for your project.

Comment: @VladimirM I already read that doc before and even I am getting my JSON response in successCallback function but my issue is I am not getting that data in table

Answer (score 0):

Try getting this to work with a success and error function as callbacks:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

In the bottom of that page there is an example for JSON response. First of all if you do a request in browser for that php file, can you put it here in the question(to see the output)